# Scraping urbandictionary with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib2

I'm currently working on an arcbot and I'm trying to make a command "!urbandictionary", it should scrape the meaning of a term, the first one which is provided by urbandictionary, if there's another solution, e.g. another dictionary site with a better api that's also good. Here's my code:

```
if Command.lower() == '!urban': 
    dictionary = Argument[1] #this is the term which the user provides, e.g. "scrape"
    dictionaryscrape = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term='+dictionary).read() #plain html of the site
    scraped = getBetweenHTML(dictionaryscrape, '<div class="meaning">','</div>') #Here's my problem, i'm not sure if it scrapes the first meaning or not..
    messages.main(scraped,xSock,BotID) #Sends the meaning of the provided word (Argument[0])
```

How do I correctly scrape a meaning of a word in urbandictionary?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: You're right, I didn't really ask it correctly. I'm trying to find out how to correctly scrape a meaning of urbandictionary, thanks!

Comment: You can download a pre-scraped csv file from here: https://www.kaggle.com/therohk/urban-dictionary-words-dataset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just  get the `text` from the `meaning` class:

```
import  requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
word = "scrape"
r = requests.get("http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term={}".format(word))

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

print(soup.find("div",attrs={"class":"meaning"}).text)

Gassing and breaking your car repeatedly really fast so that the front and rear bumpers "scrape" the pavement; while going hyphy
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Padraic, I'm really happy now! 2 bad I can't vote up yet nor set you as best answer, I will once I can. Thanks!

Comment: @algatronic. no prob,  happy botting!

Answer (score 1):

There is an unofficial api here apparently

```
`http://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term={word}`
```

From https://github.com/zdict/zdict/wiki/Urban-dictionary-API-documentation

Comment: If it's on official website how is it unofficial?